# Implementing Linear-search algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I just opened the algorithms unlocked book and I am trying to implement the pseudocode they have for a linear-search in the book in Javascript.

Here's my code

```
var answer = 'not found';

function LinearSearch(A,n,searchQuery) {
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if A[i] === value {
      answer = i;
    }
  }
}

var names = ["Jack", "Molly", "Tristan", "Jacob", "Steph"]

console.log(LinearSearch(names, names.length, "Jacob"));
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: missing `()`  for if condition and you are not returning any value from function

Answer (score 1):

There were several issues with code in your question:

- value was not defined, most probably you wanted to use searchQuery
- missing parenthesis on if A[i] === value (a syntax errors)
- n was never used (so I have removed in the code below)
- missing return statement

```js
    function linearSearch(data, searchQuery) {
      var answer = 'not found';
      for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (data[i] === searchQuery) {
          answer = i;
        }
      }
      return answer;
    }

    var names = ["Jack", "Molly", "Tristan", "Jacob", "Steph"]
    var result = linearSearch(names, "Jacob");
    console.log(result);
```

Alternative you can use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as well posted by John.
Or you could using a more exotic approach using [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

`findIndex()` is particularly useful when you have an array of objects and need to get the index my and object property. You can also use the same result using using `forEach()`.

Example using findIndex():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```js
function findIndexByName(data, name) {
  var result = data.findIndex(function(element, index, array) {
    if (element=== name) {
     return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  return result;
}
var data = ["Jack", "Molly", "Tristan", "Jacob", "Steph"];
var result = findIndexByName(data, "Jacob");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var answer = 'not found';

function LinearSearch(A,n,searchQuery) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if( A[i] === searchQuery) {
      return i 
    }
  }
  return answer
}

var names = ["Jack", "Molly", "Tristan", "Jacob", "Steph"]

console.log(LinearSearch(names, names.length, "Jacob"));
```

Syntax errors:

Line 5: change `if A[i] === value` to `if( A[i] === searchQuery)`

a function must return somthing.

**EDit**

you can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method for short code.

```js
var names = ["Jack", "Molly", "Tristan", "Jacob", "Steph"]
function LinearSearch(name){
  return names.indexOf(name) !== -1 ? names.indexOf(name) : 'not found'
}
console.log(LinearSearch("Tristan"))
```

Comment: How come you only did 'return i'? Does the function stop executing once the if statement is true and skips over the return 'answer' line?

Comment: `answer = i; return answer;` its the same as `return i` ( the second one better ), and yeah once the loop find the name it return the index ( `i ` ) then the function stop runing.